# Multiple images not inserted into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, file-upload

I am unable to insert multiple images into  database. When I am inserting the images, only one image is inserted. not all inserted. I have shown here the form with php insert code.I have not found where the problem is. Plz help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});

input[type="file"] {display: block;}
.imageThumb {max-height: 75px; border: 2px solid; padding: 1px; cursor: pointer;}
.pip {display: inline-block; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;}
.remove { display: block;background: #444;border: 1px solid black;color: white;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;}
.remove:hover {background: white;color: black;}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Upload your images</h3>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

This is php code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
      if(isset($_FILES['files']))
         {

        $n_arrays = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        $tmp_name_arrays = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
        $type_arrays = $_FILES['files']['type'];
        $size_arrays = $_FILES['files']['size'];

        foreach ($tmp_name_arrays as $index => $val) 
        {
            $n_array = $n_arrays[$index];
            $tmp_name_array = $tmp_name_arrays[$index];
            $type_array = $type_arrays[$index];
            $size_array = $size_arrays[$index];

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array, "ad/data/img/".$n_array))
            {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO `image` 
                        SET `img_name` = ?, `img_type` = ?, `img_size` = ?';

                // Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
                $bound = $statement->bind_param('sss', $n_array, $type_array, $size_array);

                // Execute the prepared statement.
                $executed2 = $statement->execute();

                if(!$executed2){
                    echo "error". mysqli_error($connection);
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['s']="Images successfully saved";
                    header('location:posting_ad_image.php');
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
?>
```

I am able to upload only the last image that is uploaded last. All images are not inserted into phpmyadmin database.

Comment: just a note - with prepared statements you `prepare` them once so do that BEFORE the loop! If you were to echo out the image name within the loop do you get all images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted your loop was hitting the `redirect` on the first iteration and then sending you off before all the images could be saved and logged. The use of `prepared statements` can be done in such a way that you do the preparation and binding of variables just once but execute many times until the statement is closed.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'],$_FILES['files'] ) ) {

        $uploaded=array();

        $n_arrays = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        $tmp_name_arrays = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
        $type_arrays = $_FILES['files']['type'];
        $size_arrays = $_FILES['files']['size'];


        /* prepare the sql statement before the loop */
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `image` SET `img_name` = ?, `img_type` = ?, `img_size` = ?';
        $statement = $connection->prepare( $sql );
        if( $statement ){

            /* if the statement was prepared successfully, bind the variables that will be used later */
            $statement->bind_param('sss', $n_array, $type_array, $size_array );


            /* iterate through the images, store the image and log to db */
            foreach( $tmp_name_arrays as $index => $val ){

                $n_array = $n_arrays[ $index ];
                $tmp_name_array = $tmp_name_arrays[ $index ];
                $type_array = $type_arrays[ $index ];
                $size_array = $size_arrays[ $index ];

                if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp_name_array ) ){
                    $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name_array, "ad/data/img/".$n_array );
                    if( $bytes ){
                        $status = $statement->execute();
                        $uploaded[]=$status && $bytes ? $n_array : false;
                    }
                }
            }
            /* close the statement and db connection */
            $statement->close();
            $connection->close();

            /* remove empty entries from array - if any */
            $uploaded=array_filter( $uploaded );

            if( !empty( $uploaded ) ){
                $_SESSION['s']=sprintf("%d Images successfully saved", count( $uploaded )-1 );
                header('Location: posting_ad_image.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Ok - The following was done as a full, end-to-end test and works ok ~ you will need to edit the `$dir` variable to suit

```
<?php



    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $connection =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );



    $dir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';




    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_FILES['files'] ) ) {

        $uploaded=array();

        $sql = 'insert into `image` set `img_name` = ?, `img_type` = ?, `img_size` = ?';
        $stmt = $connection->prepare( $sql );


        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $name, $type, $size );

            foreach( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name ) {
                if( !empty( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                    $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
                    $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                    $tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];


                    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
                        $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $dir.$name );
                        if( $bytes ){
                            $status = $stmt->execute();
                            $uploaded[]=$status && $bytes ? $name : false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if( !empty( $uploaded ) ){
                $_SESSION['s']=sprintf("%d Images successfully saved", count( $uploaded )-1 );
                header('Location: posting_ad_image.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title>Multiple file upload</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='files[]' multiple />
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload & save' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Snippet from db after running and uploading a few images at once

```
mysql> describe image;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| img_name | longblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| img_type | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| img_size | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> select * from image;
+-------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| img_name                            | img_type   | img_size |
+-------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| tumblr_ook8swcsSt1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |    81124 |
| tumblr_ook8ukfiTY1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |   201061 |
| tumblr_ook8veeLgq1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |    63477 |
| tumblr_oomaozErOP1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |   283062 |
| tumblr_oomapxb8NJ1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |   577475 |
| tumblr_oomaqzKzlw1tp499co1_1280.jpg | image/jpeg |   382917 |
+-------------------------------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have changed the php code according to you. but till now one row is inserted.  I have copied from my database  :  img_id>34
img_name>[BLOB - 6 B]
img_type>image/jpeg
img_size>130279   plz help

Comment: have you checked the php error log to see if there are any clues as to what is happening?

Comment: It does not show any error. only message comes:  `0 Images successfully saved` .   only one row and one image inserted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are redirecting to page after upload fist image. You need to change your if-else statmente.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
      if(isset($_FILES['files']))
         {

        $n_arrays = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        $tmp_name_arrays = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
        $type_arrays = $_FILES['files']['type'];
        $size_arrays = $_FILES['files']['size'];

        foreach ($tmp_name_arrays as $index => $val) 
        {
            $n_array = $n_arrays[$index];
            $tmp_name_array = $tmp_name_arrays[$index];
            $type_array = $type_arrays[$index];
            $size_array = $size_arrays[$index];


            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array, "ad/data/img/".$n_array))
            {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO `image` 
                        SET `img_name` = ?, `img_type` = ?, `img_size` = ?';


                // Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);


                $bound = $statement->bind_param('sss', $n_array, $type_array, $size_array);

                // Execute the prepared statement.
                $executed2 = $statement->execute();

                if(!$executed2){ 
                                                echo "error". mysqli_error($connection);
                                                }else{
                                                    $_SESSION['s']="Images successfully saved";

                                                }
            }
        }
        header('location:posting_ad_image.php');// add it here after for loop
    }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Till now problem is same. only one row is inserted and also one image. My database `img_name` field data type is `longblob`.

Answer (score 0):

Open php. ini file from your folder and edit the max_upload_filesize =500M and save. Restart the Xamp Or Wamp and now you can upload many files.